# No logro cargar una imagen en Label

Tags: python, imagen, tkinter, python-2.x, ventana

Estoy intentando cargar una imagen en una ventana con Tkinter lo cual puse este código que he visto en algunos tutoriales, cuando corro el programa me sale una ventana en blanco.

Por lo que he estado estudiando Python acepta imágenes con formato `.png` o `.gif` ¿Habrá algún problema con la configuración de la imagen o la versión de Python o Tkinter?

```
 from Tkinter import *

 ventana = Tk()
 img = PhotoImage(file = 'juvia.png')
 widget = Label(ventana, image = img)

 ventana.mainloop()
```

Les dejo una imagen de como se ve mi ventana, gracias por su tiempo.

[image: ventana en blanco al intentar abrir una imagen]

Gracias a los comentarios de nuestro amigo **FJSevilla** me dispuse a trabajar en este codigo que estoy haciendo, por lo que me vuelve a salir en blanco y ademas de que me da problemas porque los administradores de geometria no se llevan juntos :S el codigo original es este:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
  from tkinter import *
  import tkinter as tk
  from datetime import date
  import sqlite3 # modulo de conexion con sqlite3 
  from PIL import ImageTk, Image

  class Product:
     #conexion con la base de datos
     db_lab = 'vitasis_lab.db'


  def __init__(self, window):


    self.wind = window
    self.wind.title('Vitasis Laboratorio Médico')
    self.wind.configure(background = 'gray')

    #cargando imagen
    #img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'logo QR.png')
    #label= tk.Label(self.wind, image = img).grid( row= 0, column = 0)

    img = Image.open('logo QR.png')
    img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    widget = tk.Label(self.wind, image=img_tk)
    widget.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

    #creando el contenedor
    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registro de paciente')
    frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20, sticky = W +E)
    frame.configure(background = 'gray')


    #entrada para nombre
    Label(frame, text = 'Nombre: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.name = Entry(frame, width = 30)
    self.name.focus()
    self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    #Entrada de direccion
    Label(frame, text = 'Direccion: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.price = Entry(frame, width = 30)
    self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    #Edad
    Label(frame, text = 'Edad', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 50, pady = 10)
    self.edad = Entry(frame, width = 5)
    self.edad.grid(row = 1, column = 4, pady = 10)

    #Sexo
    Label(frame, text = 'Sexo', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    self.sexo = tk.StringVar(frame)
    self.sexo.set('---------')
    sexos = ('Masculino', 'Femenino')
    self.menu_sexo = tk.OptionMenu(frame, self.sexo, *sexos).grid(row = 2, column = 4, pady = 10)

    #Entrada diagnostico
    Label(frame, text = 'Diagnostico: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 10)
    self.diag = Entry(frame, width = 30)
    self.diag.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    #Entrada medico
    Label(frame, text = 'Médico: ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 10)
    self.medico = Entry(frame, width = 30)
    self.medico.grid(row = 3, column = 4)


    #contenedor 2 orden de servicio
    frame2 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Orden de servicio')
    frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 4, columnspan = 3, pady = 20, padx = 20)
    frame2.configure(background = 'gray')

    Label(frame2, text = 'Número de Orden', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 5, pady = 10)
    #Entry(frame2, textvariable = StringVar(frame2, value = '4856'), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 5, pady = 10) #modificar para que la orden de servicio sea un numero que incremente
    message1 = Label(frame2, text = '', fg = 'red', font = ('Verdana', 18), bg = 'gray')
    message1.grid(row = 2, column = 5, pady = 10)  
    message1['text'] = '4856'

    #contenedor 3 fecha
    frame3 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Fecha de ingreso')
    frame3.grid(row = 3, column = 5, columnspan = 3, pady = 5, padx = 20)
    frame3.configure(background = 'gray')
    fecha_actual = date.today()
    message2 = Label(frame3, text = '', fg = 'red', font = ('Verdana', 18), bg = 'gray')
    message2.grid(row = 3, column = 5, pady = 10)
    message2['text'] = '{}'.format(fecha_actual.strftime('%d, %b, %Y'))

    #contenedor 4 estudios
    frame4 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Estudios de laboratorio')
    frame4.grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 5, sticky = 'EW')
    frame4.configure(background = 'gray')
    Label(frame4, text = 'Pruebas Clinicas 1', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 3, column = 0, pady = 10, sticky = W + E)
    self.prueba = tk.StringVar(frame4)
    self.prueba.set('---------------------------------------------------------------')
    pruebas = ('ANTIDOPING EN ORINA', 'BIOMETRIA HEMATICA COMPLETA BHC', 'COPROPARASITOSCOPICO EN SERIE DE 3', 'EXAMEN GENERAL DE ORINA', 'ESPERMATOBIOSCOPIA DIRECTA','EXUDADO FARINGEO CON ANTIBIOGRAMA', 'GLUCOSA DESTROXIS', 'GLUCOSA', 'GONADOTROFINA CORIONICA FRACCION BETA', 'GRUPO SANGUINEO Y FACTOR RH',
               'HEMOGLOBINA GLUCOSILADA', 'PAPANICOLAU', 'PRUEBA INMUNOLOGICA DE EMBARAZO', 'GLUCOSA,COLESTEROL Y TRIGLICERIDOS', 'QUIMICA DE 4 ELEMENTOS', 'QUIMICA DE 5 ELEMENTOS', 'QUIMICA DE 6 ELEMENTOS', 'QUIMICA DE 12 ELEMENTOS', 'QUIMICA DE 18 ELEMENTOS', 'QUIMICA DE 25 ELEMENTOS','QUIMICA DE 32 ELEMENTOS',
               'REACCIONES FEBRILES', 'TAMIZ METABOLICO NEONATAL CON AMINOACIDOS COMPLETO', 'TIEMPOS DE COAGULACION TTPA,TP, TS, TT', 'UROCULTIVO', 'VDRL', 'VIH PRUEBA DE TAMIZAJE', 'PERFIL HORMONAL FEMENINO BASICO', 'PERFIL HORMONAL GINECOLOGICO','PERFIL LIPIDOS', 'PERFIL PRENATAL', 'PERFIL PROSTATICO', 'PERFIL REUMATICO', 
               'PERFIL TIROIDEO COMPLETO')                
    self.menu_prueba = tk.OptionMenu(frame4, self.prueba, *pruebas).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W + E, pady = 10)

    #contenedor 5 observaciones
    frame5 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Observaciones')
    frame5.grid(row = 8, column = 0, pady = 5, sticky = 'EW')
    frame5.configure(background = 'gray')
    Label(frame5, text = ' ', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, )
    self.obs = Entry(frame5)
    self.obs.grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 10, ipadx = 290, ipady = 30 )

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      window = Tk()
      application = Product(window)
      window.mainloop()
```

Tomé en consideracion quitar el wildcard (from Tkinter import *) y me arrojo un el error:

**File "vitasis.py", line 160, in** 
    **window = Tk()**
**NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined**

Se que no esta definido pero entonces como deberia quitar ese error???

despues lo volvi a dejar como estaba y me dio este problema:

**_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack**

se que esto es debido a que no se llevan pack y grid pero no tengo una idea de como los puedo poner de manera independiente :S 
por lo que decidi sustituir las lineas siguientes:

```py
         img = Image.open('logo QR.png')
         img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
         widget = tk.Label(self.wind, image=img_tk)
         widget.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
```

por estas otras lineas:

```py
        #cargando imagen
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'logo QR.png')
        label= tk.Label(self.wind, image = img).grid( row= 0, column = 0)
```

dandome como resultado esta ventana :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que estoy haciendo mal???

muchas gracias en verdad por todo su apoyo

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema de tu código es que **no usas ningún administrador de geometría** para posicionar tu widget en la ventana, por lo que nunca se mostrará el label. Debes usar `pack`, `grid` o `place`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='juvia.png')
widget = tk.Label(ventana, image=img)
widget.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Además, por lo que muestra tu error, es posible que tengas un problema con el formato de tu imagen. Si realmente es png (la extensión no es garantía de ello) no debes tener ningún problema. **Tkinter soporta por defecto imágenes GIF y PGM/PPM**.

Si necesitas usar imágenes en cualquier otro formato necesitas instalar [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (fork de PIL) usando pip.

> python -m pip install pillow

Una vez instalado, el código debería ser algo así:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


ventana = tk.Tk()
img = Image.open('juvia.png')
img_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
widget = tk.Label(ventana, image=img_tk)
widget.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
ventana.mainloop()
```

> Para Python 3.x solo cambiar el import de Tkinter por `import tkinter as tk`

Dos observaciones:

- Usar *wildcard* (`from Tkinter import *`) es una mala práctica en general en Python y solo debe usarse cuando realmente sea necesario. Aunque es común en tutoriales de Tkinter, se debe evitar usar. La razón es que dificulta la legibilidad del código, pero sobre todo, es muy fácil causar solapamientos de nombres con identificadores definidos por nosotros o en otros paquetes importados. Además puebla el espacio de nombres actual de forma innecesaria.
- Si estás aprendiendo Python, te aconsejo olvidarte de Python 2 si no tienes una razón de peso para usarlo. La rama 2.x perderá su soporte oficial en Enero del año que viene, poco más de  seis meses. Actualmente Python 2.x no recibe nuevas características, solo correcciones de bugs y seguridad.

Comment: Gracias amigo FJSevilla por tus observaciones, una disculpa por responder hasta ahora tuve un poco de trabajo y a la programacion lo hago como una manera autodidacta de aprender, de hecho en un primer instante crei que tenia instalado la version 3.7, lo tuve que volver a instalar XD, que bueno que me haces la observacion de que no estoy usando administradores de geometria, hay algun sitio donde pueda leer mas sobre como le puedo dar un tamaño en especifico a la imagen y asi poder posicionarla como si fuera un encabezado????

Comment: Hola Johny, los tres los puedes usar para lo que planteas, todo dependerá de la estructura general de la ventana. Además recuerdda que puedes (y lo común) anidar usando Frames y combinar distintos gestores. Documentación hay bastante, pero en Español escasea, aunque para eso estamos aquí nosotros :). Puedes mirarte https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm, https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm y https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm.

Comment: Amigo FJSevilla, logré desplegar las imagenes pero ahora quise meterlo en el programa que estoy haciendo en el cual me ayudaste tambien y me arrojó que la imagen volvió a salir en blanco ademas de que en algunas ocasiones, me arrojaba el error de _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack lo que estuve leyendo es que grid y pack no se llevan juntos porque hacen un loop verdad??? podrias revisar mi codigo para decirme que tengo mal??? sigo atorado :(

Comment: Johnny lo de la imagen en blanco suele ser porque el recolector de basura elimina la imagen al perder la referencias (creada localmente en una función por ejemplo). Lo segundo que comentas es exactamente como dices, puedes usarlos juntos pero anidando adecuadamente widgets no en un mismo widget simultáneamente. Si quieres puedes editar la pregunta y añadir tu código actual, pero deja intacto lo que ya tiene para que no quede los comentarios y respuestas sin contexto.

Comment: eres muy amable, reedite la pregunta

Comment: El problema de la imagen se soluciona simplemente manteniendo una referencia con `self._image_logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)` y `widget = tk.Label(self.wind, image=self._image_logo)`. En cuanto a lo otro solo solo evita usar grid y pack en el mismo contenedor, si quieres usar ambos usa otro frame para englobar ¿La imagen debería colocarse como cabecera arriba del todo ocupando todo el ancho de la ventana? ¿Cuanta altura debería ocupar? Tengo la misma  duda en cuanto a la localización de Orden de servicio y Fecha de ingreso con respecto a los otros frames.

Comment: FJSevilla eres la onda!!! muchas gracias, lo que hice mal fue que no puse una referencia con self y por eso salia en blanco??? o como se puede explicar ese error???? 
Con respecto a lo de la imagen, de hecho busco que se ocupe toda la ventana en la parte de arriba pero eso se soluciona acomodando las filas y columnas o debo de ocupar el width y heigth?? 

Lo que es orden de servicio debe de estar a la altura de registro de paciente y fecha de ingreso abajo de orden de servicio que de igual manera se soluciona ajustando mis filas y columnas es correcto???